# How to change the int value onclick and pass it to another activity ? on android?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I want to change (int x) when i click on (button x) and pass int x value to  another activity.
and change (int y) when i click on (button y) and pass int y value to  another activity.

how to do that on android ?

Answer (score 1):

`I want to change (int x) when i click on (button x)`

this is trivial, you create listener for your button and inside it you alter your variable x (defined in your activity A)

`and pass int x value to another activity.`

you need to put this `x` value inside Intent bundle

`and change (int y) when i click on (button y) and pass int y value to another activity.`

this is exactly the same as above, but for variable y/button y

is it a homework?

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreference. Save in A1 and retrieve in A2 and vice-versa.

**Initialization**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Storing Data**

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

**Retrieving Data**

```
// returns stored preference value
// If value is not present return second param value - In this case null
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

**Deleting Data**

```
editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

**Clearing Storage**

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Answer (score 1):

1 activity

```
int x=value;
Intent i=new Intent(this, secActiv.class);
i.putintextra("x",x);
startactivity(i)
```

2 activity

```
oncreate(){...
Intent i=getintent();
int x=i.getintextra("x",null);
```